# What is the best way to clean your dvd-burner?

Tags: dvd, cleaning, optical-drive, burning

What is the best way to clean your dvd-burner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ed Bott found that these CD lens cleaners actually work shockingly well:

http://www.edbott.com/weblog/?p=2703

> I probably turned 30 disks into coasters while investigating this problem, trying every troubleshooting trick I know to find the source of the problem. Converting the source files to WAV format and caching them locally didn’t help. The problem wasn’t software, either, as I found by repeating the issue with multiple burning programs, including Media Monkey and Easy Media Creator 10.
>
> In several forum posts, I had read recommendations for special disks designed to clean the laser on a CD/DVD player/burner [..] When I received the product and removed it from its packaging, I have to confess I was skeptical. It looks like a regular music CD with instructions on the label side and a half dozen small brushes arranged in a track on the bottom (shiny side) near the center of the disk. In Windows Media Player, it plays like a music CD, with 14 tracks that include audio instructions delivered in a friendly female voice, along with some test tones to help you determine whether your speakers are wired correctly.
>
> After completing the entire suite of tests in 10 minutes or so, I popped in a blank CD, fired up Media Monkey, and told the software to burn a collection of FLAC files from a network location to CD, converting them to WAV files in a local cache on the fly. Surprise! The first disk burned just fine. As did a second, a third, and a fourth.

Amazon links for [Memorex lens cleaner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00008EM7U), [Allsop lens cleaner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00000J1QM)

Answer (score 1):

Probably some sort of lens cleaner.

[http://www.amazon.com/Allsop-23321-Carbon-Edge-CD-Drive-Cleaner/dp/B00000J1QM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000J1QM)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard one of the best things to do is get some compressed air cans and use short bursts of air to try and clean it out a bit...

From what I've heard, don't poor liquids directly into the drive.  It tends to break things...

Answer (score 0):

In the early days of CD players, 20+ years ago, I used a bit of Chamois leather and some Isopropyl alcohol to clean both CD's and laser lenses, remember not to follow the data path when cleaning discs (don't clean in a spiral, go from the center to the outer edge or the reverse). This method applies to the latest 4K Ultra HD Blu Ray Discs too. If you are cleaning the lense on your disc player - be gentle they are fragile....